# Despite try-catch-block: Error occurs when clicking undefined element in Selenium/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, error-handling

I am using Selenim and JavaScript for some ui tests. I have written a function so that the test script does not crash when errors occur. However, when clicking an undefined element, the script crashes with the error "Cannot read property "click" from undefined in  at line number 1)" - see code below.

I am using Nashorn Java Script engine and an self-coded testrunner.

```
function tryCatch(testMethod) {

    try {
        testMethod();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error");
    }
}

//Calling testmethod

    tryCatch(function () {
        driver.findElement(By.id("testId")).click();
    });
```

I expected the script to run after the element is not found and clicked successfully

Comment: Try this one 
'tryCatch(function(){
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id("testId")).click();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("error");
    } finally {
        print("Finally");
        throw "finally-thrown";
    }
})();'

Comment: @KuldeepYadav: In the tryCatch-Method I already have a catch block -  why should I add a second one?